# replacing loops when comparing multidimensional arrays

Tags: r

I am working with multi-dimensional arrays, and making comparisons for each element. So far, I have been using loops, but I was wondering how I could use apply(or another better function to avoid the loops). I am not sure ..I tried several ways, but it is not working fine.

Let's say the following example, where I compute the 95 percentile for the elements of the 3-dimension, and then I make a comparison:

```
       m <- array(1:30, c(5,4,3))
       mp <- apply(m,1:2,quantile,probs=c(.95),na.rm=TRUE) 
       temp      <- array(dim=dim(m))

       for(i in 1:5){
         for(j in 1:4){
            temp[i,j,] <- m[i,j,]>mp[i,j]
         }
       }
```

I don't know if apply can be used here(I read some posts but still not sure), is there any other way to avoid the loops??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vectorization and assigning dimensions after the evaluation of your condition:

```
 array(as.vector(m)>as.vector(mp),dim(m))
```

Comment: I saw your answer only after posting.  This would be the way to go.  You can make it compact with `c` `array(c(m)>c(mp),dim(m))`